# DIPlib: Converting a dip::Image object to a vigra::MultiArrayView object with dip_vigra::DipToVigra not working

Tags: c++, image-processing, diplib, vigra

I am facing some trouble when I try to convert from a `dip::Image` object to a `vigra::MultiArrayView`. The way vice versa works fine, but when I try to call `dip_Vigra::DipToVigra` I am getting:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘DipToVigra(dip::Image&)

How should I do this conversion?

As said, the way vice versa works fine with `dip_vigra::VigraToDip()`

```
vigra::FImage Img;
Img.resize(width, height);
vigra::MultiArrayView<2, float> VigraView = Img;
dip::Image DIPimage;

DIPimage = dip_vigra::VigraToDip(VigraView); // works fine

VigraView = dip_vigra::DipToVigra(DIPimage); // fails
```

I am working on opensuse using code::blocks as IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `dip::Image` has properties (dimensionality and pixel type) defined at runtime, and `vigra::MultiArrayView` has properties defined at compile time through template parameters, the templated function `dip_vigra::DipToVigra()` needs explicit template parameters for the compiler to know what the output type is.

That is, the compiler can automatically determine template parameters for `dip_vigra::VigraToDip()`, but not for `dip_vigra::DipToVigra()`.

So you need to explicitly mention these parameters:

```cpp
VigraView = dip_vigra::DipToVigra<2, float>(DIPimage);
```

Note that, at runtime, the function will check that the properties of `DIPimage` match the given template parameters, and error out if they don't.

The repository has an example C++ program that shows how to convert images between DIPlib and Vigra: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/examples/external_interfaces/vigra_with_dip.cpp